# Core Data vs LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, cocoa

As far as I read about Core Data it sounds to me a lot similar to LINQ to SQL. Am I very wrong? If I am why am I?

I realize that LINQ to SQL doesn't to all that Core Data does, but some of the functionality is similar, isn't it? If it isn't does Cocoa have something similar to LINQ to SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL vs ADO.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671179/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net)

Comment: why qould it ever be duplicate? Core data- objective c cocoa, and LinQ to SQL is .net and so is ADO.net

Comment: Oh! Sorry (; My mistake here.

Comment: If you're using Swift, and want something similar to LINQ to SQL for CoreData, try Core Data Query Interface at https://github.com/prosumma/CoreDataQueryInterface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would say that LINQ is closer to being equivalent to [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) in Cocoa since it provides a means of querying collections of several types, as does NSPredicate.

Core Data is probably closer to being the equivalent of ADO since it is a means of providing a persistent store whose logical structure can support your model.