# Connection to a distant database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a WPF application that contains two databases(local and distant).I'd connect to the distant database and execute some queries of selection (no modification) , for the local one I need to read,delete and update many informations. I have to choose between Ado.net and Linq to sql.

So, what is the best choice between them and what are the configuration parametrs needed in the distant Sql Server to accept connection from other PC?

Comment: This question is not constructive at all, you need to elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried already. Try reading documentation on connecting to databases before asking vague questions here.

Comment: [This may be of interest to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671179/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net)

Comment: `Distant` do you mean a `REMOTE DB`..? are you familiar with Linq..? if not why not utilize the `SqlCommand` object as well as the `SqlDataClient`

Comment: @Clint what exactly you didn't understand

Comment: Define "distant"? Are there firewalls between the client and database? Personally when I hear "distant", I'm thinking "http api", meaning: write two versions of the DAL (sharing an `interface`) - one that talks ADO.NET, and one that talks http (maybe WCF, maybe not).

Comment: @DJKRAZE i mean by distant a database in other server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to choose between Ado.net and Linq to sql.

LINQ-to-SQL is basically an ORM wrapper around ADO.NET. However, when I hear the word "distant", I would usually assume that direct ADO.NET connectivity is no longer appropriate. If the boxes are on different networks, or separated by firewalls / sub-nets / etc, then the most appropriate thing would be to expose your data via a web-service (that *internally* may use ADO.NET or LINQ-to-SQL, but that is entirely an implementation detail). That web-service could be exposed via WCF, ASMX, ServiceStack, manually-implemented REST, or any other kind of web-based access technology you like the look of.

Then the only question is: when running on the *same* network ("local" in your example)... should it continue to use the web-service (for code-reduction, etc), or should it also have a direct (ADO.NET / LINQ-to-SQL) connection option? The first would be no extra code (because the web-service already exists to support "remote" clients); the second (direct) option *may* in ***some*** (limited) scenarios have some performance advantages.