# what are differences between linq and linqToSql queries?

Tags: linq

I am going to use LINQTOSQL in my projects and all queries are already in LINQ. So what changes I have to make in my queries.Is their any other format for LINQTOSQL queries.

Comment: Please research first - possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL vs ADO.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671179/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq is the "Language-Integrated Query" feature added to C# and that can be used against a variety of sources (Linq to SQL, Linq to Entity Framework, Linq to Objects, Linq to XML, Linq to Datasets etc...)

Linq to SQL is the outdated way to use Linq to access SQL Server databases (Linq to Entity Framework is preferred now). It's quite common to just talk about "Linq" even when actually talking about "Linq to Entity Framework"

Answer (score 0):

[Linq2Sql](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb386976(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=o8uXVcSyOdDhuQSKgofIBw&usg=AFQjCNFFNVA2m7POB7MQw0WTzTaCQZjxjw&sig2=YmfX40hY2fmrUbRKgJBw_A&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E) is an [ORM framework](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FObject-relational_mapping&ei=y8uXVYPjAZaeugTDz5W4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFXHm_KxOsSMJ1hGZ6SAiiJlQcCdA&sig2=ANkhTf9ybEXG-Bq4_u_P0w&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E), only work with SQL Server, developed by Linq2Sql team.

[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is also an ORM framework, developed by ADO.NET team, work with many database systems like SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL,...

Later ADO.NET team taken Linq2Sql team, they concentrate on developing Entity Framework till today, Linq2Sql is in maintenance mode.

Linq2Sql is faster about performance than Entity Framework. But Entity Framework provide range of options to deal with database such as Code First, Database First, Model first...

Linq2Sql is Linq work with Sql Server database.